# Debugging browser crash via CLI

Tags: linux, browser

I'm preparing for an interview and came across this question in a forum:

> If your browser crashes, how would you debug it only using the command line?

For simplicity, let's assume it's a Firefox browser on a *nix environment. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: There don't appear to be any interesting [arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments#List_of_command_line_arguments_.28incomplete.29) that aid in verbosity. The best reference I can find is that Firefox uses the [Breakpad](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Breakpad) reporting system, which dumps crash ID's to [file](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Breakpad#Using_the_file_system_to_view_crash_reports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they say crashed browser are we talking about an actual bug in firefox or a plugin that results in a crash?

Debugging is possible, but it assumes a developer experience.

Use `ulimit -c` to make sure your system will actually create a [core dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) with the application crashes.  Then use [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) (*nix) to debug.  You will probably want to download the source code for the browser.  You may want to recompile your browser with the [debug symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_Firefox_with_Debug_Symbols).

Unless the question is for a developer position though I doubt you would be expected to be able to do this.

Are you sure they are asking how to debug a crashed browser, or are they talking about finding a network issue which should be very easy to diagnose from a command line.  In that case you would be using something like `ping`, `nslookup`, `traceroute`, and so on.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Remote_debugging#Core_dumps_on_Mac_and_Linux

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, for general purpose debugging, especially for an application that you don't have the source for, try [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) and or ltrace.
There's a good basic introduction to strace [here.](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/010aug05/features/strace/) There are similar programs for windows.

```
strace firefox
```